# Next.js Site shows crawlers empty body - No content except populated props

Tags: next.js, indexing, seo, google-search-console

When I go to google search console and type the homepage of my project in ([www.esfaras.de](http://www.esfaras.de)) and click live check -> show image it shows a blank page. The code shows an empty body and only the props from GetStaticProps populated as well as the other code inside next/head component.

Seo and Analytics sites like Ahref or Semrush also cannot see and fetch other sites based on the provided project homepage link.

The only way it works for Ahref crawling service for example is when i active "execute javascript". I researched a lot but still cannot understand why my Projects index page with GetstaticProps needs javascript execution to be crawlable

I have no clientside code running in pages/index.js only receiving 2 props from GetStaticProps and passing them to some Child Components.

The project is hosted on a vpn with nginx

Additionally I want to add that I know google can index pages and execute javascript. And that it already did that in my case, I just didn't know it was this dramatic I thought everything was "normal".

Please someone help.

Answer (score 0):

What i figured out is as soon as you use an UseEffect somewhere you enable CSR which means client-side-rendering. After creating a test branch and ripping apart half my application:

- i managed to actually get a server side rendered html page served.
- had to disable basically google analytics.
- application monitoring third party init
- complete header comp
  ...

So.. what am i going to do now. Is the restructuring worth it to only have some pages server side served? My whole project is based on UseEffect and based on its dependency array activities setting and changing states. I will start to switch to function based state changing instead of listening to other states. Sometimes i will have to call 2-3 functions in one action call but that seems nessessary.